# AspectJ and Kotlin - injecting a Spring service

Tags: spring, kotlin, aspectj

```
@Aspect
@Component
class ExceptionAspect(private val mailSenderServiceImpl: MailSenderServiceImpl)
{
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* myproject.mail..*(..))", throwing = "throwable")
    fun sendError(throwable: Throwable)
    {
    mailSenderServiceImpl.send(recipient = "email@gmail.com", subject = "Exception", content = "We have got a problem here!")
    }
}
```

This part of code gives me this stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: Exception while initializing myproject.mail.aspect.ExceptionAspect: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: myproject.mail.aspect.ExceptionAspect: method <init>()V not found
at myproject.mail.aspect.ExceptionAspect.aspectOf(ExceptionAspect.kt:1)
at myproject.mail.handler.MessageHandler.handleMessage(MessageHandler.kt:23)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:438)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: myproject.mail.aspect.ExceptionAspect: method <init>()V not found
at myproject.mail.aspect.ExceptionAspect.ajc$postClinit(ExceptionAspect.kt:1)
at myproject.mail.aspect.ExceptionAspect.<clinit>(ExceptionAspect.kt:1)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$Constructor.call(FunctionCaller.kt:66)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:107)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod(KCallableImpl.kt:149)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:111)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils$KotlinDelegate.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:738)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1126)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:387)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
at myproject.mail.MailBotKt.main(MailBot.kt:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

I tried injecting it to the field by using lateinit var or by setting it to null by default, but I had no success(NPE, in case of lateinit - tells me that the field has not been initialized..). What can be done about it?

Thanks!

I made a minimal example that reproduces the problem:
https://github.com/ashofthephoenix/spring-boot-ltw

Comment: Does the aspect work without the parameter?

Comment: I think, it is looking for a default constructor of `ExceptionAspect`

Comment: @kriegaex yes. when I replace the mail sending with a `println` then it works fine(if that's what you meant, I might have misunderstood)

Comment: @amdg `if all of the parameters of the primary constructor have default values, the compiler will generate an additional parameterless constructor which will use the default values.`

Comment: Same problem persists when I port it to Java.

Comment: (1) No, that is not what I meant. I was talking about the primary constructor. As AspectJ or Spring AOP - depending on which one you use - usually instantiate aspects by themselves, you need a default constructor without parameters. I just wanted to know if the aspect as such works. (2) Your primary constructor parameter does not have a default value, so there will be no default parameter-less constructor. (3) Do you use full AspectJ with LTW or proxy-based Spring AOP?

Comment: @kriegaex i use AspectJ with LTW, although I had to make a configuration (in Spring) class, this one exactly: https://hastebin.com/dubotipero.scala otherwise the aspect wouldn't work.

Comment: I defined a constructor without parameters and the problem still persists.

Comment: I am not a Spring expert, only an AspectJ one. But somehow this looks different from what the Spring manual suggests. Maybe it makes sense to share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub for everyone to be able to see and reproduce your problem.

Comment: i added the example to the question, please take a look if you want (i removed the InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver since I noticed the problem still persists without it)

Answer (score 0):

I had to declare an aspect Bean in my configuration class and use aspectOf(), also add @Inject(or @Autowired) on the service in the aspect. And that's it.

```
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@Configuration
open class AspectConfiguration : LoadTimeWeavingConfigurer
{
   override fun getLoadTimeWeaver(): LoadTimeWeaver = InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver()

   @Bean
   open fun aspect(): ExceptionAspect = Aspects.aspectOf(ExceptionAspect::class.java)
}
```